# Create table that is table 1 minus table 2 based on three criteria

Tags: sql

I have a table of LoggedDischarges and another table of ActualDischarges.

I am trying to generate a query that will give me all the fields from ActualDischarges excluding those already in LoggedDischarges based on AgencyID, Program and ActivityEndDate

A client can be in multiple programs and be discharged from multiple on the same day.  I need to make sure I get LoggedDischarges from each program.

This is what I have but am not sure how to add the other criteria.

```
    select * from ActualDischarges
    where (agencychildid ) not in
          (select agencyid from LoggedDischarges)
```

Thank you,

Steve Hathaway

Comment: Left join and filter by null will give the desired result..

Comment: Which database are you using? Please add the relevant tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if your DBMS supports multiple columns in a subquery like

```
where (AgencyID, Program, ActivityEndDate) not in
   ( select AgencyID, Program, ActivityEndDate 
     from ... )
```

you better switch to a NOT EXISTS (in case of any NULLs):

```
select * from ActualDischarges as aD
where NOT EXISTS
   (select * from LoggedDischarges as lD
    where aD.AgencyID = lD.AgencyID
      and aD.Program = lD. Program 
      and aD.ActivityEndDate= lD.ActivityEndDate)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed.  I was trying to do the And's in the wrong places.

Answer (score 1):

For this type of match, I would recommend a LEFT JOIN with an IS NULL at the end to determine that the second table does not have the record:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM ActualDischarges AS a
LEFT JOIN LoggedDischarges AS l
ON agencyid=agencychildid
AND a.program=l.program
AND a.ActivityEndDate=l.ActivityEndDate
WHERE l.agencyid IS NULL
```

As a side note, definitely avoid using multiple IN statements for situations like this WHERE NOT IN (...) AND NOT IN (...) etc. as you end up excluding records which match different records in LoggedDischarges for different reasons, which is rarely the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for this, I will try this approach also.